# Local connection between android studio with sql server

Tags: android

I'm new on android programming and the sql server. I'm trying to connect an android application to a SQL local Server database. i do not know how to connect android application and sql server using local ip address.

Comment: you can use volley or retrofit library

Comment: thank you! im using retrofit but i do not know how to connect with using local machine ip address , like this    // public static final String CLOVENT_API_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:63628/";

Comment: set it as base url like `http://10.0.2.2:63628/`